# Python steamlit select box menu returns string, but I need dict or list

Tags: python, streamlit

Stack on this case, Python steamlit select box menu returns string, but I need dict or list, to use it further in my code.
I want to see company1, company2, company3 in dropdown menu, and if user's choice was  for example 'company2' get `['ID': 'zxc222’, 'NAME': 'company2','DESC': 'comp2']`.

```
BaseObject = [{
    'ID': 'zxc123',
    'NAME': 'company1',
    'DESC': 'comp1'
}, {
    'ID': 'zxc222',
    'NAME': 'company2',
    'DESC': 'comp2'
}, {
    'ID': 'zxc345',
    'NAME': 'company3',
    'DESC': 'comp3'
}]

lenbo = len(BaseObject)
options = []
for i in range(0, lenbo):
    options.append((BaseObject[i])['NAME'])
st.selectbox('Subdivision:', options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the conversion to a `dict` after the `selectbox`:

```py
import streamlit as st

BaseObject = [{
    'ID': 'zxc123',
    'NAME': 'company1',
    'DESC': 'comp1'
}, {
    'ID': 'zxc222',
    'NAME': 'company2',
    'DESC': 'comp2'
}, {
    'ID': 'zxc345',
    'NAME': 'company3',
    'DESC': 'comp3'
}]

lenbo = len(BaseObject)
options = []
for i in range(0, lenbo):
    options.append((BaseObject[i])['NAME'])
choice = st.selectbox('Subdivision:', options)

chosen_base_object = None
for base_object in BaseObject:
    if base_object["NAME"] == choice:
        chosen_base_object = dict(base_object)

print(chosen_base_object)  # {'ID': 'zxc345', 'NAME': 'company3', 'DESC': 'comp3'}
```